# How do you populate an SSRS TextBox with a DataSet value?

Tags: reporting-services

Dear community member,

Given a specific *Key* (e.g. "user_name"), how does one populate an SSRS `TextBox` with the corresponding `DataSet` *Value* (e.g. "John Doe")?

Any insight you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

**CONTEXT**

- SQL Server = 2008 R2
- IDE = Visual Studio 2012
- *ReportData* `DataSet` contains data used to populate a `Tablix` in the body of the report
- *HeaderData* `DataSet` contains data used to populate two `TextBox` elements in the report header

  - this `DataSet` contains two columns: *key* and *value*

**CONSTRAINTS**

- for this particular problem, I cannot simply bind the *HeaderData* `DataSet` to a `Tablix` in the report header... I have to populate `TextBox` elements
- If a report contains multiple `DataSets`, and you reference the `Fields` collection in an expression... you will receive a "The Value expression for the text box users an aggregate expression without scope" error.

**SAMPLE DATA**

*HeaderData*

Key="camera_name", Value="Panomera - Terminal 1"

Key="user_name", Value="John Doe"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using a Dataset called `HeaderData` like:

[image]

I have a couple of textboxes in a report header:

[image]

Where the expression above is:

```
=Max(IIf(Fields!Key.Value = "user_name"
  , Fields!Value.Value, Nothing)
  , "HeaderData")
```

This is working OK:

[image]

This works as it uses the `IIf` expression to NULL out any values other than when `Key` = *user_name*, then takes the `Max` of the non NULL `Value` values.

Since you're referencing a Dataset outside of a tablix you need a Scope and an aggregate - I'm using `Max` to ignore NULL values, which something like First will not do. Judging by your description there should only ever be one non NULL value there so it should be fine.

Comment: For reference, my colleague found an alternative answer: `=Lookup("user_name", Fields!key.Value, Fields!value.Value, "HeaderData")`