# SSRS Binding Textbox to a field from the query

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a question similar to this one: 
[How do you populate an SSRS TextBox with a DataSet value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19160730/how-do-you-populate-an-ssrs-textbox-with-a-dataset-value)

I'm on old release 2012 R1 and designing report in Visual Studio 2010 shell.

I want user to enter a specific order number, and thus the query will return just one row. I want to show the fields down the page (better for viewing/printing), instead of across the page like the normal table does (especially if I have so many fields that they don't fit on the width of one screen).

Example: 
[image]

Don't I just bind the textbox to a database field on the properties using DataElementName.  That's what I didn't understand about the post I referenced above. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  I clicked Action then was able to select the database field from a list.  After that, I also noticed I can right click, then click "Expressions", and the following screen appears:

[image]